# Datatype & conditional constructs

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 float f = 0.1;
        if (f == 0.1)
            printf("True");
        else
            printf("False");
  return 0;
}
```

The above code is given in my class test. 
I was expecting true as the output but False was the output.
WHy?

Comment: because `0.1` has type `double` and `0.1f != 0.1` ... `float fx = 1.0/10; double dx = 1.0/10; printf("%d\n", dx == fx);` If you compare with `float` you get what you expect: `if (f == 0.1f)` or `if (f == (float)0.1)`

Comment: Suggestion: **always** (yes, always) use `double` when you want to work with floating-point values.

Answer (score -1):

In c language a float variable contain by default 7 decimals but you compare it with only one decimal in your if check. you can write f after decimal value to represent all decimals. Now it will answers True.

Like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 float f = 0.1;
        if (f == 0.1f)
            printf("True");
        else
            printf("False");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not what `f` means.